# CSS3 solid drop shadow effect mixin using stylus

Tags: css, stylus

So I want to achieve an effect of a drop-shadow like the one seen here: http://zurb.com/playground/css-boxshadow-experiments#peri-table

But I want to create a mixin that allows me to specify the length of the drop shadow, my first approach was:

```
solidShadow(size, color = #000)
    shadows = '0px 0px #000'
    for n in size
        shadows += ', ' + n + 'px ' + n + 'px '
        shadows += color
    return shadows
```

Being called `box-shadow solidShadow(1..3)` This "works" but the actual output is

```
-webkit-box-shadow:'0px 0px #000, 1px 1px #000, 2px 2px #000, 3px 3px #000';
box-shadow:'0px 0px #000, 1px 1px #000, 2px 2px #000, 3px 3px #000';
```

Which would work correctly if the single quotes ***'*** where not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The answer was the unquote() function so it ended up looking like this.

```
solidShadow(size, color = #000)
    shadows = '0px 0px #000'
    for n in size
        shadows += ', ' + n + 'px ' + n + 'px '
        shadows += color
    return unquote(shadows)
```

And being called `box-shadow solidShadow(1..3)`